# WooCommerce: readonly billing fields in checkout and account page - but not if empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have working code for the function in woocommerce of readonly for billing fields in the checkout and my-account area. but i need a fallback if the field is empty.

my code for readonly fields is:

```php
function xyz_readonly_billing_account_fields ( $fields ) {
    // Only my account billing address for logged in users
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ( is_account_page() || is_checkout() ) ) {

        $readonly = ['readonly' => 'readonly'];
        $fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_company']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_address_1']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_address_2']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_state']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
        $fields['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'xyz_readonly_billing_account_fields', 25, 1 );
```

Can anyone help me out?

i have tried a way like this

```php
 if ( ! empty( $fields['billing_first_name']['value'] ) ) {
        $fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = $readonly;
    }
```

not working :-/

and

```php
function xyz_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
        if($key == 'billing_first_name' || $key == 'billing_last_name' || $key == 'billing_email' || $key == 'billing_company' || $key == 'billing_country' || $key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2' || $key == 'billing_city' || $key == 'billing_state' || $key == 'billing_postcode' || $key == 'billing_phone'){
            $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
            if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_fields;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','xyz_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
```

works on checkout, but not for address edit page on my-account.